# Ruby on Rails Scoping code block to remove the need for arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, helper

I come from PHP and CakePHP background and I'm pretty new to ruby and rails.

I've been creating a helper that could help me with creating some HTML elements that could make me easy to reuse across the web app that I am creating.

Here's how the snippet of my helper looks like

```
module VehicleHelper
  def mileage(vehicle)
    render partial: "vehicles/shared/mileage", { locals: vehicle }
  end
  def manufacturer(vehicle)
    render partial: "vehicles/shared/manufacturer", { locals: vehicle }
  end

  #and etc...
end
```

And I would use it this way in haml.

```
%h1= @vehicle.name


= mileage @vehicle
= manufacturer @vehicle
-# and etc…
```

I want to be able to scope it, so that I don't need to give `@vehicle` as an argument for every function. Like

```
%h1= @vehicle.name


- vehicle_block_for @vehicle do
  = mileage
  = manufacturer
  -# and etc…
```

How do I achieve it? Is that a right pattern that I should use?

**Edit** : I have thought of using partials straight in the view. However, the problem is that I not only have `Vehicle` class, I also have `Car` and `Bike` classes which are sub-classes of `Vehicle`, following the STI pattern.

Which means I will have to pass locals all the time, in which case `= render partial: 'mileage', { locals: vehicle}` or what not becomes configuration codes. And let's say I've renamed the file or moved it somewhere, then I'd have to go and modify all these codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About whether this is a "right pattern" for you to use, that's entirely up to you. If you like the way it makes the code read, then great. The simplest implementation would be something like:

```
 module VehicleHelper
   def vehicle_block(vehicle)
     old,@__vehicle__ = @__vehicle__,vehicle
     yield
     @__vehicle__ = old
   end

   def mileage
     render partial: "vehicles/shared/mileage", { locals: @__vehicle__ }
   end
 end
```

Comment: Can I ask what is the use of the variable `old`?

Comment: Making the passed vehicle apply only for the duration of the block, and making it possible to nest calls to `vehicle_block`. It may not ever make a difference, but anyways...

Answer (score 1):

You could just make the render calls directly in your view and it will automatically have access to your instance variable "@vehicle"... I believe those views would have access to "@vehicle" as we'll using the helper methods you currently have, no need to pass it as an argument.

I would also check out the presenter/decorator pattern for this. There is a Railscast for it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that a right pattern that I should use?

I would say no. Yes, you're shortening the code but at the cost of making things harder to follow/understand. A new user to your project would have to search around for the definition of the "mileage" method. Once they find it in the helper they would have to go look at the partial. All that for what, showing less code in the view? I don't think it's worth it.

I would revert it back to something like the following which IMHO is much easier to follow and more idiomatic rails.

```
%h1= @vehicle.name

  render partial: 'mileage', { locals: vehicle }
  render partial: 'manufacturer', { locals: vehicle }
```

Note: I would also explicitly pass in the `locals` instead of using `@vehicle`. It makes things, well, more explicit.

Comment: I have thought of this. The problem is that I not only have `Vehicle` class, I also have `Car` and `Bike` classes which are sub-classes of `Vehicle`, following the STI pattern.

Which means I will have to pass `locals` all the time, in which case `= render partial: 'mileage', { locals: vehicle}` or what not becomes configuration codes. And let's say I've renamed the file or moved it somewhere, then I'd have to go and modify all these codes.

Comment: @MikeHan I'd mention the stuff in your comment here in the original question. That will help clear up why you're trying to do something like this.